# Параллельные вычисления в нейросетях

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, нейронные-сети

Имеется нейронная сеть со следующей структурой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я последовательно выполняю тренировку нейронной сети, прогоняя через неё набор тренировочных данных, а именно:

1) **Прямое прохождение сигнала** (inputs) **через каждую матрицу весов** (да да да, сумматор, функция активации, все дела...)

2) **Расчёт ошибки выходного слоя** (сопоставление outputs и targets)

3) **Расчёт ошибки скрытых слоёв** (производная функции активации, учёт влияния матрицы весов на ошибку, все как надо)

4)**Поправка весовых коэффициентов**  (с учётом вычисленной ошибки)

Эти действия в процессе обучения выполняются N раз (100......1000000)

**Вопрос? Как можно организовать вычисления параллельно ?**
ведь цикл обучения для каждого из наборов входных значений, подразумевает работу с текущими значениями матриц весов. Чтобы обновить веса для одного набора inputs(x1....xn), нужно на этих весах рассчитать outputs(Y-1...Y-m), выполнить поправку и только потом загонять следующий inputs(x....)... ну с соответствующим набором targets(y......) конечно же

//нейронная сеть уже написана на С/C++ в планах использовать несколько потоков для ускорения работы (Просьба не кидайте ссылки работ на CUDA, я знаю что он похож на Cи и там всё работает, я не могу понять что конкретно вычисляется параллельно и как эти результаты влияют друг на друга, для получения результирующего набора матриц весов)

**UPD**: как это примерно сейчас работает(слой *абстрактный*)

```
for (out = 0 ; out < outputsNeuerons ; out++)
 {
     float sum = 0.0;
     for (inp = 0 ; inp < inputsNeuerons ; inp++)
     {
    //inputs - то что вошло в слой
     sum += inputs[inp] * weightsMatrix[inp][out];
     }
     sum += weightsMatrix[inputsNeuerons][out];

    //outputs -  то что вышло из слоя 
    outputs[out] = sigmoid( sum );
 }
```

Comment: Очевидным вариантом будет параллелить вычисления для каждого слоя. Кидаете n / число потоков нейронов в каждый поток.

Comment: то есть одновременно считать прямое прохождение например 2-х входных векторов(пусть 2 потока), одновременно мы сможем и вычислить ошибку с выходов и рассчитать ошибку на каждом слое. Но что делать с поправкой? Если набор матриц один а наборов поправок уже 2. Корректно ли рассчитывать значения поправок для разных inputs(x.....xN) без внесения поправки "предыдущего расчёта"? Не нарушится ли работа градиентного спуска в поправке коэффициентов?

Comment: Я нигде не упоминал про одновременную обработку двух входных векторов.

Comment: @VTT тогда как понять "параллелить вычисления для каждого слоя"?  чтобы пройти очередной слой нужно пройти предыдущий, только последовательно можно прогнать сигнал через всю сеть

Comment: Я же расписал - распределяете вычисления для нейронов каждого слоя между n потоков. Вычисления для каждого следующего слоя начинаются после окончания всех вычислений предыдущего слоя.

Comment: @VTT тогда где "параллельность"? в итоге все равно пока входной вектор не перемножится  на Матрицу_1, он не будет перемножен на Матрица_2, какая разница 1 поток последовательно работает с входным вектором или несколько потоков последовательно передают входной вектор друг другу для вычисления в текущем слое?

Comment: Перечитайте еще раз то, что я написал выше. Несколько потоков производят параллельные вычисления в одном и том же слое, с одним и тем же входным вектором.

Comment: @VTT зачем нам считать значения одного и того же вектора в одном и том же слое в нескольких потоках одновременно??? это же одно и тоже ! Или вы предлагаете "распилить"  матрицу весов на 2 потока? если да то хотелось бы более наглядно на это взглянуть, как пол матрицы перемножает один поток и как другой поток работает с оставшейся половиной. Так же можно?

Comment: Я уже не знаю как объяснять... Вот у вас на картинке нарисованы несколько кружков, относящихся к первому слою. Допустим 6 штук. Первый поток обрабатывает кружки первого слоя с номерами 1, 2, 3; второй поток - кружки первого слоя с номерами 4, 5, 6 - Параллелизм!

Comment: VTT имеет в виду следующее: Разбейте один слой на N групп персептронов. Так как каждый персептрон обрабатывает свои входы независимо от своих соседей, то мы можем каждую группу назначить своему потоку, который будет рассчитывать её независимо от других. То есть мы всё так же вычисляем слой за слоем, вот только вычисления *внутри* слоя распараллеливаются.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Структурная схема параллельной работы нейронов из разных потоков]

Делим входной вектор на 2 (условно) части, каждая половина считается в своём потоке, результирующие вектора суммируем и отправляем получившееся на функцию активации.

//Замечания в комментарии (и да сумму двух векторов на картинке не корректно записана)

Для одного потока:

```
for (out = 0 ; out < outputsNeuerons ; out++)
 {
     outputs[out] = 0.0;
     for (inp = 0 ; inp < inputsNeuerons/2 ; inp++)
     {
     outputs[out]  += inputs[inp] * weightsMatrix[inp][out];
     }
     outputs[out]  += weightsMatrix[inputsNeuerons][out];
 }
```

Для другого потока:

```
for (out = 0 ; out < outputsNeuerons ; out++)
 {
     outputs[out] = 0.0;
     for (inp = inputsNeuerons/2; inp < inputsNeuerons; inp++)
     {
     outputs[out]  += inputs[inp] * weightsMatrix[inp][out];
     }
     outputs[out]  += weightsMatrix[inputsNeuerons][out];
 }
```

**//если это чушь, то хоть дайте знать**

Comment: `результирующие вектора суммируем` - нет. 1) Внутри текущего слоя есть какое-то количество персептронов (нейронов, грубо говоря), выход которых записывается в вектор, передаваемый следующему слою на вход. 2) Значение каждого элемента вектора зависит только от предыдущего слоя и не зависит от соседей. 3) Благодаря независимости от соседей мы можем разбить вектор на куски и каждый кусок отправить вычисляться в свой поток. Так как потоки работают только со своими элементами и не лезут к соседям, мы получаем ускорение во столько раз, сколько у нас потоков.

Comment: 4) То есть вектор выходных значений слоя получается точно таким же, как в однопоточном варианте, просто его элементы рассчитываются не друг за другом, а одновременно (почти).

Comment: (ответ к свежей правке) Да, верно.

Comment: @Arhad правильно ли я понял что мы пилим входной вектор на N одинаковых частей(равное количеству потоков). И каждая часть будет работать параллельно со своими, недоступными другим, участками матрицами?